# Install FastCGI on IIS7.5 Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: iis-7.5, fastcgi

I would like to install FastCGI on IIS 7.5 on my Windows 7 Home Premium box I use at home to do some random coding. However WPI doesn't show the FastCGI option and I can't find it in IIS at all...

How do I do this just one installer, I've seen FastCGI installs for IIS 5.1 and IIS6 but it says FastCGI should be a part of IIS already... It is not in WPI and not in "Turn windows features on or off"...

I'm lost!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run a separate install to use FastCGI.  It is integrated with IIS7.5 but you need to activate the CGI feature on your machine.  To do this:

1. Go to Control Panel...Programs...Turn Windows Features on or off.
2. Expand Internet Information Services...World Wide Web Services...Application and Development Features.
3. Check the box next to CGI.
4. Click 'OK'.

After the feature activation finishes, go to IIS manager on your local machine.  You should see the FastCGI Settings under the 'IIS' section.

A TechNet article provides more detail [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753077%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Configuration details for FastCGI on TechNet are provided [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239230%28WS.10%29.aspx).